# Send Email If Filename Exists

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

I'm trying to setup a simple one-liner to search to see if a file exists and if it does, emails me to let me know.

This is the command I'm using to search:

```
find . -name "error_log"
```

Basically I just want to use `sendmail` or something similar to shoot me an email if an `error_log` file is generated.  Doesn't need to be anything fancy, just a simple message like "File exists".

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: find . -iname 'filename' -exec sendmail 'do something. Search on google for find exec and man is always your friend (man find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

rm /tmp/log
find . -name "error_log" > /tmp/log
[[ -s /tmp/log ]] && mail -s 'error logs' you@domain.tld < /tmp/log
```

Comment: Isn't that limiting searches to `/tmp/log`?  I have the error_log files being created in various directories...

Comment: I found several tutorials like this, but none of them seem to show how to search all directories:  https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/find-out-if-file-exists-with-conditional-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "error_log" | ifne mail -s 'error logs' you@domain.tld
```

ifne is part of moreutils (debian)